# Can it be determined for what $N$ a sum of $k$th powers $\sum_{n=1}^N n^k$ is equal to an $m$th power of an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can it be determined in some form of closed presentation (e.g. a quick test that can be applied to $N$, or a formula for $N$) for what $N$ a sum of first $N$ $k$th powers $\sum_{n=1}^N n^k$ is equal to an $m$th power of an integer? If it can't always be done (or it isn't known whether it can) for arbitrary $m,k$, then for what $m,k$ can it currently be done?

Comment: There is no general form for the equation when $k>3$ and $m\geq 2$

Answer (score 0):

It is true for $k=3,m=2$ for all $N$ because the sum is $\frac 14N^2(N+1)^2=\left(\frac 12N(N+1)\right)^2$

Solutions for $k=1,m=2$ come from solving the Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=\pm 1$  Each solution $(x,y)$ gives rise to a solution $\sum_{n=1}^Nn=\frac 12N(N+1)$ which is a square when $N$ is the lesser of $x^2,2y^2$.  For example (3,2) gives rise to $\sum_{n=1}^8n=\frac 128(9)=36=6^2=(xy)^2$ and $(7,5)$ gives rise to $\sum_{n=1}^{49}n=\frac 12(49)(50)=1225=35^2=(xy)^2$